# Time selection is not working in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have below post code. I have append a html code for table body (`tbl_body`). There are time selection fields as `fe_date` and `fs_date`. but the time selection window does not show.
Please help me.

```
$.post("<?php echo base_url('controller/function_name') ?>", {'cid': cid},
    function (data)
    {
        if (data.length > 0) {
            $('#tbl_body').find('tr').remove();
            for (j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
                $('#att_st_time'+(j+1)).datetimepicker({pickDate: false});
                $('#att_end_time'+(j+1)).datetimepicker({pickDate: false});
                $('#tbl_body').append("<tr><td style='width:14%;text-align: center'>" + (j + 1) + "</td><td style='width:25%;text-align: center'><input class='form-control' id='att_st_time"+(j+1)+"' data-validation='required' data-validation-error-msg-required='Empty is field' type='text' name='fs_date' time-format='H:M:S' value='" + data[j]['ttlc_starttime'] + "'> </td><td style='width:25%;text-align: center'><input class='form-control' id='att_end_time"+(j+1)+"' data-validation='required' data-validation-error-msg-required='Empty is field' type='text' name='fe_date' time-format='H:M:S' value='" + data[j]['ttlc_endtime'] + "'></td></tr>");
            }

        }
    },
    "json"
);
```

Comment: `type='time'`? can you elaborate more what you want..

Comment: I want to use bootstrap timepicker like interface https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a class to your `input` like `class="form-control date-picker"`

Then try to add this code.

```
$(document).on('focus',".date-picker", function(){
    $(this).datetimepicker();
});
```

Comment: `$(this).datetimepicker({pickDate: false});` I changed like this because I wanted only time. Now working right. Thanks :)

Comment: @tenten i'm glad I was able to help.. Just mark this as the answer for +rep for both of us ^_^..